# About the expression "be heard to"

Tags: expressions

> My uncle was head copy editor of the NY Times for 20+ years. Neither my mother nor my father **was ever heard to say** anything that was not grammatically 
>   correct. It’s in my DNA and I can’t help it.

Does it mean "his/her parents were never told to say something that is not grammatically correct"?

Doesn't the word "heard" should be replaced by "told"?
Is it a well-written, confusion-free paragraph?
Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It's a quite correct phrase. Changing *heard* to *told* would result in a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means, that no one has ever heard either the mother or the father say something, which was grammatically incorrect.

I think, you just misunderstood it, because in my opinion it is quite understandable.